# Jinja2/Flask dynamic variable name change

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have a Flask method and index.html snippet with a jinja2 for loop

```
def recommendations():
    return render_template("index.html", score1='46', score2='12', score3='15', score4='33')
```

index.html:

```html
{% for i in range(1,5) %}
   <p> Your score: {{ score1 }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

How do I dynamically change the names of the score variable based on the loop like:

```html
<p> Your score: {{ score1 }}</p>
<p> Your score: {{ score2 }}</p>
<p> Your score: {{ score3 }}</p>
<p> Your score: {{ score4 }}</p>
```

Comment: I've already tried {% for i in range(1,5) %} <p> Your score: {{ score + i }}</p>{% endfor %}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't create dynamic variables in Jinja2. You should instead use a list:

```
return render_template("index.html", scores=['46', '12', '15', '33'])
```

or a dictionary:

```
return render_template("index.html", scores={
    'score1': '46', 'score2': '12', 'score3': '15', 'score4': '33'})
```

and adjust your Jinja2 loop accordingly to handle that instead. For the list that's as simple as:

```
{% for score in scores %}
   <p> Your score: {{ score }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

For the dictionary case you could use sorting to set a specific order:

```
{% for score_name, score in scores|dictsort %}
   <p> Your score: {{ score }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

and you could use `score_name` to display the key as well.